# ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format in Oracle Insert using Select

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-insert

I have below query where i am getting error as `ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format`. The `C_DATE` column is Date datatype.

```
INSERT INTO CS_LOG(NAME, ID, C_DATE)
Select MAX(ML.NAME), ML.ID, TO_CHAR(CHK_DATE,'YYYYMM')
from D_ID ML,
     CS_LOG MD
WHERE ML.NAME != MD.NAME
  and ML.ID != MD.ID
  and MD.C_DATE = LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY ML.ID, C_DATE;
```

Comment: sysdate is already supposed to be a date. try to apply `last_day` function directly

Comment: How is the `select` statement alone ? if you execute without the insert, you receive error ?

Comment: Alone select statment is working without insert

Comment: then we need the structure of target table and source tables. Please provide the ddl

Comment: So what data type is `chk_date`? Sounds like that is varchar, and need to be explicitly converted to a date with a suitable format mask? (And as said before don’t do `to_date(sysdate...)` even if that currently works, it’s pointless and will break with different NLS settings.)

Comment: @Alex sorry its C_DATE and its data type is date. I have updated the query which i am trying and its giving the error. Because i want to insert in C_DATE with format YYYYMM

Comment: Your latest edit now has a YYYYMM string being implicitly converted to a date during the insert. What is that supposed to be doing? Do you just want the first day of the month of the`chk_date` value?

Comment: i want the last day of the month during insert in the format YYYYMM to be inserted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t insert a date ‘with a format’. Dates have an internal representation, they always have all the date/time components and can then be formatted for display however you want.

The string you’re generating as YYYYMM is being implicitly converted to a date by the insert, as that is the target column’s data type. That implicit conversion is using your NLS settings, and from that is expecting a longer value to match the NLS date format. Your string doesn’t match that implicit format, which is causing the error you’re seeing.

If you’re only interested in the year and month then the closest you can get is to store midnight on the first of the month, which you can get with `trunc`:

```
INSERT INTO CS_LOG(NAME, ID, C_DATE)
Select MAX(ML.NAME), ML.ID, TRUNC(CHK_DATE,'MM')
from D_ID ML,CS_LOG MD
WHERE ML.NAME != MD.NAME and ML.ID != MD.ID
and MD.C_DATE = LAST_DAY(sysdate)
GROUP BY ML.ID,C_DATE;
```

I’ve also removed the extra `to_date` call. You should consider switching to ANSI join syntax too.

You can then format `c_date` as YYYYMM for display when you query it, if that is what you need, via `to_char`.

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to insert into a date, a varchar which is YYYYMM
that's is normal that you have an error.

Try insert a real date, not just month and year

Comment: Actually i want to insert in that format only. Is it not possible ?

Comment: TO_CHAR(CHK_DATE,'YYYY-MM-01')

Comment: no. It is not possible. It is meaningless. a date is a date. The output format is cosmetic and should be changed only in your select query when you retrieve the information

Comment: if you want to store it with a specific format, then it is a string, not a date anymore